# VS2010 and WPF slow debug issues

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, performance, visual-studio-2010

im (like a lot of other people) doing my first steps in vs2010.

one of the things i just found which really annoys me is that each time i try to debug a WPF application the ide slows down so each movement from one statement to the other results in 10 sec. (!) waiting.

what can i do ? is there a nice solution (besides not using WPF:)

adiel.

Comment: Are you using something like Resharper? That can slow things down.

Comment: no im not using any plug-in code editing helper.

by the way changing the FW from 4.0 to 3.5 solves the problem.

the thing is i must use 4.0 for its Parallel extensions.

Comment: Did you disable IntelliTrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the slowness issue was mainly a result of visual source safe with a very problematic user.

This can be solved in three ways :

1. Disable VSS - you can turn it back on later.
2. Run using the admin the analyze on the vss db (actually a file system).
3. Use a new clean vss user.

Answer (score 0):

```
    1)Which version of VS2010 are you using RC or the RTM?

    2)What is your machine's spec? Does it comply with the minimum requirements of VS2010?
    (if you're using single core processor you're screwed kidding...) 

    3)Try defragmenting the partition in which you've installed VS2010?
```

Comment: 1. vs2010 premium RTM !
2. my machine meets the min. req. by far - core 2 quad q6600, 2GB ram
3. the drive was defragmented a week ago.

any other ideas ?